# What are the pros and cons of multiclassing a Dragonborn Paladin with either Sorcerer or Warlock? and when and if to swap over

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, paladin

My Dragonborn Paladin is nearing the end of level 2, (Str3, Dex0, Con2, Int-1, Wis-1, Cha3, with Defensive giving AC19).

The main group I play with, he is the only Tank, unless my 10 year old daughter, joins in with her Circle of the moon Druid

She is the only child in the group and you can't rely on her to focus on battle tactics :)

----------------new below ------------------

My initial goal was to create a super paladin, I tend to play him as a tank with healing, saving my limited spell casting for just the right time due to limited spell slots, so I hardly ever use it. I once even died holding onto the valuable spell slots because I forgot about them.

However, once I started looking into it, I haven't found that perfect sweet spot, that balances out the Spell Slinging Tank Front Man. All the options I've looked at have drawbacks that make me wonder if it is a combo that is worth pursuing

Just hoping for that splash of inspiration to make it all come together.

Comment: I have a feeling this is pretty broad. What is your goal with the character that we can measure the pros and cons against? DPS? Control? Support? Why are you interesting in Sorcerer and Warlock? How far will your character get in levels over your play with it?

Comment: We probably also need to know which flavour of sorc or warlock you are referring to, some work really well, some don't

Comment: Also what oath were you heading towards?

Comment: Also note that multiclassing isn't a flat swap over; you can even go back-and-forth since you pick which class levels up each time you gain a level.

Comment: Tangentially related on [What do I lose by going paladin 17/Warlock 3 instead of 1 additonal or 1 level fewer in Warlock?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152698/what-do-i-lose-by-going-paladin-17-warlock-3-instead-of-taking-1-additional-l) Many of the answers go over pros and cons multiclassing in general with paladins.

Comment: This seemed pretty straight forward to me: "What are the benefits for a Paladin of multiclassing Warlock and/or Sorcerer" Although it might deserve being split into two questions, one for the Sorcerer/Pally combo, one for the Warlock/Pally combo.

Comment: @revenant The problem (at least for me) is that it also asks how/when to multiclass, which is a large number of options/orderings. A clear goal/role/method and expected initial/final levels would be a must, and it may still be too broad

Comment: @Medix2 well, the *how* is easily answerable, as the PHB covers that. From an optimization standpoint, the *when* does have a definitive answer. As for role, it has been expressed that the character is a tank, and will likely need to continue to fill that role going forward. This is certainly clear enough to anyone who reads the question to be able to suggest what steps can be taken, and at what point they should be taken.